# Re-Create Better Lines in Legend Using PostPaint Event for Chart Created Dynamically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, charts, paint, legend

I am trying to modify line thickness in the legend of a dynamically-created Chart1 object, using the PostPaint Event listed below.  However, the code below assumes that Chart1 exists on a form.  Is there a way to find out when the Paint Event is fired, and then implement this PostPaint Event?

```
 Private Sub Chart1_PostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs) Handles Chart1.PostPaint

        If TypeOf e.ChartElement Is Legend Then

            Dim c As Chart = CType(sender, Chart)
            Dim g As Graphics = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics

            'The legend
            Dim l As Legend = c.Legends(0)

            'Absolute dimensions of the legend (New legend will be based on this.. won't be exact.)
            Dim pos As RectangleF = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(l.Position.ToRectangleF)

            'Absolute dimensions of one legend "cell"
            Dim itemHeight As Single = pos.Height / c.Series.Count
            Dim itemWidth As Single = pos.Width / 2

            'Padding between line and text (horizontal) and each item (vertical)
            Dim horizontalPadding As Single = 10
            Dim verticalPadding As Single = 1

            Dim legendFont As New Font("Arial", 10)

            'Draw a white box on top of the default legend to hide it
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, pos)

            For i As Integer = 0 To c.Series.Count - 1

                Dim s As Series = c.Series(i)
                Dim p As New Pen(s.Color, CSng(Math.Min(s.BorderWidth, itemHeight))) 'Line no thicker than the item height.

                'Line
                Dim posY As Single = CSng(pos.Y + (verticalPadding * i + itemHeight * i + itemHeight / 2))
                Dim startPoint As PointF = New PointF(pos.X, posY)
                Dim endPoint As PointF = New PointF(CSng(pos.X + itemWidth), posY)
                g.DrawLine(p, startPoint, endPoint)

                'Text
                posY = CSng(pos.Y + verticalPadding * i + itemHeight * i)
                startPoint = New PointF(CSng(pos.X + itemWidth), posY)
                g.DrawString(s.Name, legendFont, Brushes.Black, startPoint.X + horizontalPadding, startPoint.Y)

            Next

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Tried it, but the Handles Chart1.PostPaint event throws an exception because the Chart is created dynamically.  There's not an easy button for this, so you would need to be creative on suggesting how to run the code inside this method on a dynammically-created Chart.  There has to be a work around(?)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION for Right docking of Legend (see Bottom docking below): It worked out that I also had a ChartDashStyle setting for each series line, as well as a Legend font and size specified.  I modified the above code and tweaked it quite a bit with various pixel adjustments to move the new legend up and to add spacing between lines based on the font size for the legend.  I also added some logical statements to convert the ChartDashStyle to the GDI+ DashStyle.

After you dynamically create an e.g. Chart1 object, and process all code to fill the series, etc, all you need to do to call the PostPaint event for the chart is to add the following code at the end of all chart processing code:

```
Dim Chart1 As New Chart
Chart1.Invalidate()
Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()
Chart1.Legends.Clear()
Chart1.Series.Clear()
.
.
(fill series datapoints, legend, titles, etc)
.
.
AddHandler Chart1.PostPaint, AddressOf Chart1_PostPaint
```

The PostPaint event will fire after painting, and then call the method (subroutine below) to re-create the legend with colored lines, with appropriate thickness and dashstyle based on those same properties for each series.

(There does not need to be a `Handles...` at the end of the subroutine's definition)

```
   Private Sub Chart1_PostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ChartPaintEventArgs)

        If TypeOf e.ChartElement Is Legend Then

            Dim c As Chart = CType(sender, Chart)
            Dim g As Graphics = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics

            'The legend
            Dim l As Legend = c.Legends(0)

            'Absolute dimensions of the legend (New legend will be based on this.. won't be exact.)
            Dim pos As RectangleF = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(l.Position.ToRectangleF)

            'Absolute dimensions of one legend "cell"
            Dim itemHeight As Single = pos.Height / c.Series.Count + 30
            Dim itemWidth As Single = pos.Width / 2
            'Padding between line and text (horizontal) and each item (vertical)
            Dim horizontalPadding As Single = 10
            Dim verticalPadding As Single = l.Font.Size  

            Dim legendFont As Font = l.Font

            'Draw a white box on top of the default legend to hide it
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, pos)

            For i As Integer = 0 To c.Series.Count - 1
                Dim s As Series = c.Series(i)
                Dim p As New Pen(s.Color, CSng(Math.Min(s.BorderWidth, itemHeight))) 'Line no thicker than the item height.
                Dim ds As ChartDashStyle = s.BorderDashStyle
                'Line
                Dim posY As Single = CSng(pos.Y + (verticalPadding * i + itemHeight * i + itemHeight / 2)) - (c.Series.Count + 2) * verticalPadding
                Dim startPoint As PointF = New PointF(pos.X, posY)
                Dim endPoint As PointF = New PointF(CSng(pos.X + itemWidth), posY)
                p.DashStyle = ds
                If ds = ChartDashStyle.Solid Then
                    p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
                End If
                If ds = ChartDashStyle.Dash Then
                    p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash
                End If
                If ds = ChartDashStyle.DashDot Then
                    p.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDot
                End If
                If ds = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot Then
                    p.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot
                End If
                g.DrawLine(p, startPoint, endPoint)

                'Text
                posY = CSng(pos.Y + verticalPadding * i + itemHeight * i) - (c.Series.Count + 2) * verticalPadding
                startPoint = New PointF(CSng(pos.X + itemWidth), posY)
                g.DrawString(s.Name, legendFont, Brushes.Black, startPoint.X + horizontalPadding + 5, startPoint.Y - 5)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is an example resulting legend: [image: legend]

For Bottom docking of the legend, the code had to be totally reworked, and the results are below:

```
Private Sub Chart1_PostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ChartPaintEventArgs)

    If TypeOf e.ChartElement Is Legend Then
        Dim c As Chart = CType(sender, Chart)
        Dim g As Graphics = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics

        'The legend
        Dim l As Legend = c.Legends(0)

        'Absolute dimensions of the legend (New legend will be based on this.. won't be exact.)
        Dim pos As RectangleF = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(l.Position.ToRectangleF)
        Dim numrows As Single = Math.Max(Math.Floor(pos.Height / l.Font.Height), 1)
        'Absolute dimensions of one legend "cell"
        Dim itemHeight As Single = pos.Height / numrows
        Dim numcols As Integer
        If c.Series.Count = 1 Then numcols = 1
        If c.Series.Count = 2 Then numcols = 2
        If c.Series.Count = 4 Then numcols = 4
        If c.Series.Count = 3 OrElse c.Series.Count > 4 Then numcols = 3
        Dim itemWidth As Single = pos.Width
        If c.Series.Count = 1 Then itemWidth = pos.Width
        If c.Series.Count = 2 Then itemWidth = pos.Width / 2
        If c.Series.Count = 4 Then itemWidth = pos.Width / 4
        If c.Series.Count = 3 OrElse c.Series.Count > 4 Then itemWidth = pos.Width / 3
        itemWidth *= 0.9
        'Padding between line and text (horizontal) and each item (vertical)
        Dim horizontalPadding As Single = 10
        Dim verticalPadding As Single = 1

        Dim legendFont As Font = l.Font
        'Dim legendFont As New Font("Arial", 10)

        'Draw a white box on top of the default legend to hide it
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, pos)

        For i As Integer = 0 To c.Series.Count - 1

            Dim s As Series = c.Series(i)
            Dim p As New Pen(s.Color, CSng(Math.Min(s.BorderWidth, itemHeight))) 'Line no thicker than the item height.
            Dim ds As ChartDashStyle = s.BorderDashStyle
            If ds = ChartDashStyle.Solid Then
                p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
            End If
            If ds = ChartDashStyle.Dash Then
                p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash
            End If
            If ds = ChartDashStyle.DashDot Then
                p.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDot
            End If
            If ds = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot Then
                p.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot
            End If
            Dim row As Integer
            If c.Series.Count = 4 Then row = Math.Ceiling((i + 1) / 4)
            If c.Series.Count <> 4 Then row = Math.Ceiling((i + 1) / 3)
            Dim col As Integer
            If c.Series.Count = 1 Then col = 0
            If c.Series.Count = 2 Then col = i Mod 2
            If c.Series.Count = 4 Then col = i Mod 4
            If c.Series.Count = 3 OrElse c.Series.Count > 4 Then col = i Mod 3
            'Line
            Dim posx As Single = CSng((pos.X + (horizontalPadding + itemWidth * (col - 1)) + itemWidth / 2))
            Dim posY As Single = CSng((pos.Y + (verticalPadding + itemHeight * (row - 1)) + itemHeight / 2))
            Dim startPoint As PointF = New PointF(posx + itemWidth * 0.75, posY)
            Dim endPoint As PointF = New PointF(CSng(posx + itemWidth), posY)
            g.DrawLine(p, startPoint, endPoint)

            'Text
            posx = posx + itemWidth
            startPoint = New PointF(posx, posY - l.Font.Height / 2)
            g.DrawString(s.Name, legendFont, Brushes.Black, startPoint.X + horizontalPadding, startPoint.Y)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is an example of the results when Bottom docking is used:

[image]